# Fuzzy start/end address ranges in SED command

Tags: sed, range, fuzzy

How can I create a starting and ending range specification in SED that is imprecise (fuzzy)?  I need to specify a starting range greater than point A and an ending range less than point B.  Example would be a log file, running from midnite to midnite - need to limit my SED operation between the hours of A and B but I can't guarantee that an exact match on the start or end times can be had.  So I'm looking for a SED construct something like this:

```
 sed  '/>A.../,/<B.../ s/xyz/abc/g' file
```

Apply the match/edit to lines within the range greater than A and less than B.

For instance:

```
2012-12-21 00:03:44 ....
2012-12-21 01:44:12 ....
2012-12-21 02:30:13 ....
2012-12-21 04:15:16 ....
2012-12-21 05:23:05 ....
2012-12-21 07:21:22 ....
```

I want to limit the matches to anything between 3 am and 6 am.

As SED currently works, if I don't match the range precisely (particularly the ending address), it simply runs on to the end of the file, and thus matches too much.

Could do this with a complicated arrangement of grep's and/or awk but looking for a simple one-command, one line solution within SED if that's possible.

Comment: Interesting approach I hadn't thought of. Thanks!  But I may have oversimplified the example and patterns of the range(s) involved.  What if I want everything between say  11pm on one day and 3am on the next day? (This is why I got locked into thinking of a less than/greater than construct instead of an exclusion construct) But your approach might work here:  / ... date1 [t1] /,/ ... date [t2]/ {...}.  I play with that formulation and see if it'll work. I'll have to massage the t1 and t2 values first, of course before feeding it into the [..] portion of the address patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\S\+ 0[3-6]/!d' file
```

If it is not between `03` and `06` hours, delete the line.